# Monotonicity of total variation and partition

Tags: real-analysis

We can define a total variation $V(f)$ of a piecewise continuous function $f$ with partition $P=\{x_0,\ldots,x_n\}$ as follows:

\begin{align}
V(f)=\sup_{P}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lvert f(x_{i}) - f(x_{i-1}) \rvert.
\end{align}

To emphasize a specific interval, it is denoted as $V_{a}^{b}(f)$ in $[a,b]$ where $a=x_0$ and $b=x_n$. I want to prove that $V_a^x(f)$ is monotone increasing in $x\in[a,b]$. At first, I tried to figure it out showing $V_a^{x+h}(f) - V_a^x(f) \geq 0$ for $h>0$ with the same number of elements in the paritions of $V_a^{x+h}(f)$ and $V_a^x(f)$, say $n_1$ and $n_2$, respectively. But then this attempt was failed since if $n_1=n_2=1$, then $V_a^{x+h}(f) - V_a^x(f) = \lvert f(x+h) - f(a) \rvert - \lvert f(x) - f(a) \rvert$ so there is a bunch of functions satisfying $f(x+h)=f(a)\neq f(x)$, i.e., $V_a^{x+h}(f) - V_a^x(f) < 0$. Now I'm really confused. Doesn't $\sup_P$ just depend on $n$ in the definition of $V_a^b(f)$? Or does it imply that $n$ corresponding to $V_a^b(f)$ in a given $[a,b]$ is unique?

Comment: In definition of $V(f)$, why is there no $f$ in the right hand-side of the equality?

Comment: It is the $\sup$ over all partitions of the interval, each partition has some associated $n$ but it is not fixed in the definition of variation.

Comment: Consider $E=[0,1]$ and $F={-1, 2}$. Then for every $x \in E$ we have $x>-1 \in F$ BUT $\sup E=1<2=\sup F$.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni I've addressed it. Thanks.

Comment: @copper.hat Now I think that I can handle it easily. Thank you.